# ATK: Using link format with grid

Tags: atk4

I'm new with ATK, but couldn't find the solution for this. I found the example for using template on link here: https://agiletoolkit.org/whatsnew/apr2011

I create grid like this, and add link:

```
$grid=$this->add('Grid');
$grid->setModel('Application',array('name'));
$grid->addColumn('link','name')->setTemplate('<a href="..">xx</a>');
```

Which produces links like this:

```
<a href="..">xx</a>
<a href="..">xx</a>
```

I would like to achieve like this:

```
<a href="?name=1">Name 1</a>
<a href="?name=2">Name 2</a>
```

Can I achieve this with setTemplate? I should somehow insert current name and id value into template, but how to do this? Or is there some other, better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$grid=$this->add('Grid');
$grid->setModel('Application',array('name'));
$grid->addColumn('link','name')->setTemplate('<a href=".."><?$name?></a>');
```

Comment: Great! :)  like this: $grid->addColumn('link','name')->setTemplate('<a href="?id=<?$id?>"><?$name?></a>');